# Reduction between a decidable language $L$ and $\Sigma^*$

Tags: turing-machines, reductions

Is there a reduction between a decidable language $L$ and $\Sigma^*$?

Comment: What kind of reduction?

Comment: @EvangelosBampas Turing reduction.